# Marking TSC unstable due to check_tsc_sync_source failed

Tags: debian, kernel, boot, cpu

My dedicated server has been hanging it out (or just turning off) very often sometimes more than a day, apparently for no reason (according with the technical support department). After that, the only virtual IP address doesn't arise in the boot. If I do a `ifup eth0:1` the IP address works fine. The configuration is located in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Browsing `/var/log/syslog` I found some error messages, but the one caught my attention was this:

```
kernel: [    0.09204] TSC synchronization [CPU#0 -> CPU#1]:
kernel: [    0.09204] Measured 112995559 cycles TSC warp between CPUs, turning off TSC clock.
kernel: [    0.09204] Marking TSC unstable due to check_tsc_sync_source failed
```

Because, after trying to replicate the same situation in a local machine, that error message was the one relevant to appear only in the dedicated server's logs. In my local server the virtual IP address works fine after a reboot, even if NetworkManager is running but not managing the network interfaces at all.

So, seems the problem got nothing to do with any network interfaces misconfiguration at all, but with the Linux kernel and the CPU (or the BIOS). However, I don't know how to fix this issue: change the kernel or tuning up? change the CPU? upgrade or downgrade the BIOS?

```
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 7 "Wheezy"
Kernel: 3.2.0-4-amd64
CPU: Intel Xeon E312xx (Sandy Bridge)
Motherboard: Intel 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma]
BIOS: Bochs 01/01/2011
```

Comment: you could try booting with another clock, eg `clocksource=hpet` if you think it will change things. If the server hangs or turns off it may be hardware problems like power supplies, fan failure, overheating due to dry thermal paste, and so on. Try limiting the max cpu speed or turbo mode etc in your bios if it allows that to see if it survives better.  See [intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/06/20/eliminate-the-dreaded-clocksource-is-unstable-message-switch-to-tsc-for-a-stable) for a discussion of the tsc clock.

Comment: I just asked to the Web hosting company to change the CPU and motherboard, explaining why I think the dedicated server got to be changed, let's see what they answer to that. I'll take a look to the Intel forum anyway. Thanks for the advice.